# JavaScript Replace function check

Tags: javascript

I am doing a java script replace as :

```
var featureTitle;
featureTitle = row.cells[1].text();
if (!featureTitle.indexOf('*') != -1)
{
    featureTitle = featureTitle.replace('*', '');
}
```

Is **if (!featureTitle.indexOf('*') != -1)** needed check here??

OR replace will take care of it?

Comment: No need do if statement.

Comment: Your `if` statement adds confusion. `.replace()` will handle whether there is a '*' to replace or not without the need for the check

Comment: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZkUkH/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` will do nothing if the asterisk does not exist, so it's safe to call without the check first.

Speaking of which, the check has a bug which makes the code as a whole behave incorrectly:

```
if (!featureTitle.indexOf('*') != -1) // what's that ! in front doing?
```

Since `!featureTitle.indexOf('*')` is always `true` or `false`, this condition will always succeed (both booleans compare unequal to `-1`).

Comment: Is there a place where I can get my JavaScript get reviewed...I am aware of JSLint and JsHint..

Answer (score 0):

replace will work on first occurence of '*'. If there is none, then nothing will be replaced, therefore "if" is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Here is the referenced [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkUkH/1/) for you

```
if (!featureTitle.indexOf('*') != -1){...}
```

is not mandatory to place, you can do `.replace()` directly

```
var featureTitle;
featureTitle = row.cells[1].text();
featureTitle = featureTitle.replace('*', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of that if statement.  I think .replace() will take care of it(*if `*`exists it will replace it else no action*).  If you want to replace all the `*` in the string then use `\g` global attribute.

```
featureTitle = featureTitle.replace(/*/g,'');
```